# python-dev installation error: ImportError: No module named apt_pkg

Tags: python, linux, installation, debian

I am Debian user, and I want to install python-dev, but when I run the code in the shell as a root:

```
# aptitude install python-dev
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):       
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named apt_pkg
```

What seems to be the problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: looks like your apt ist broken, what happens when you try apt-get install python-dev

Comment: When I try with apt-get install python-dev it says that it is already installed: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Make sure you have a working python-apt package. You could try and remove and install that package again to fix the problem with apt_pkg.so not being located.

```
apt-get install python-apt
```

Comment: It is already installed. When I hit:

# apt-get install python-apt

it gives me

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-apt is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


And when I try again with:

# aptitude install python-dev

It gives me the same error again. Some other ideas what should I do?

Comment: remove it using `apt-get remove --purge python-apt` and install it again

Comment: Be aware of other dependencies. I removed the package (too) quickly in Ubuntu and lots of other dependencies were removed as well (e.g. ubuntu-desktop). It's my fault for not paying attention to the notes in the log, however.

Comment: Not really sure if it was due to python-apt. Look over at http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-desktop for dependencies to ubuntu-desktop.

Comment: @Arnestig REMOVING `python-apt` sounds rather dangerous!! Learnt my lesson once and I shall not try it.

Comment: Compiling python worked for me, here is the link https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5367#issue-320060428

Comment: Fixed that error, now I'm getting `ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)` :(..

Comment: @Arnestig thank you, `--purge` and then reinstalling seems to have fixed it for me

Comment: Not working after upgrade from 3.5 to 3.9.

Answer (score 278):

I met this problem when doing `sudo apt-get update`. My env is debian8, with python2.7 + 3.4(default) + 3.5.

The following code will only re-create a `apt_pkg....so` file for python 3.5

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall
```

The following code solved my problem:

1. Go to `dist-packages`

```bash
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

2. Locate the appropriate `.so` file for the python version installed on your system:

```bash
ls -l | grep apt_pkg
```

3. Create a symbolic link:

```bash
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{your-version-number}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

4. Replace `{your-version-number}` appropriately.

**CAUTION**, the following will create a symlink from apt_pkg37m to apt_pkg36m. **make sure you are linking to the correct, or at least to an existing version** by `ls apt_pkg.cpython-*`, and see which one(s) you have installed.

```bash
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

So, obviously, `python3-apt` checks the highest python version, instead of the current python version in use.

To understand why this is happening, see this answer further down: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64241654/21539

Comment: `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
should be changed to 
`sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so`

Comment: You are amazing!  For me, it was `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,36m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` for python3.6, and this horrific bug is now gone.

Comment: I needed to run `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt`

Comment: After installing Python 3.7 next to the default 3.6 in Ubuntu 18.04 with `sudo apt install python3.7` I got this apt_pkg error trying to run pip, so I needed to run `cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` then `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{36m,37m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` then `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

Comment: for python 3.6, command will be `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{35m,36m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: @AlexGurrola Verified in Ubuntu 16.04 on 22Aug2019

Comment: What does the ln command do? I have never seen braces used that way before. Looks like some kind of black magic.

Comment: Those braces are not a property of the the ln command. They invoke shell brace expansion, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

Comment: for me no 'm', just the python version number `apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

Comment: still relevant for 2023 on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: It worked for ubuntu 18.04 and python version 3.8

Answer (score 197):

Solve it by this:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
cp apt_pkg.cpython-34m-i386-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Or:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
cp apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Basically, if you get a `No such file or directory` just `ls` to try to get the right name.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, use this

$ cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
$ sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so

Comment: This worked for me as well...
I listed all the files on the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, and I saw that I didn't have of `apt_pkg.cpython-34m-i386-linux-gnu.so` or `apt_pkg.cpython-3m-i386-linux-gnu.so`, but I had `apt_pkg.cpython-36m-i386-linux-gnu.so`... I copied this file to `apt_pkg.so` and worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me as well. As @LeonardoIsso did I also listed all files to find the proper file name because i am on 32 bit Linux.

Answer (score 121):

This happened to me on Ubuntu 18.04.2 after I tried to install Python3.7 from the deadsnakes repo.

Solution was this

1) `cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`

2) `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so`

Comment: Just wanted to confirm to others that this indeed worked for me.

Comment: that's crazy, thank you! When in docker: `RUN ln -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so`

Comment: this is the solution! After upgrading to python 3.7.

Comment: 18.04.04, upgrading to python 3.7 and this worked for me as well! Thanks!!

Comment: Works for python 3.8 also !

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me for python3.7

Comment: The accepted solution didn't work, but this one did.

Comment: works for me as well

Comment: Same Reason here !! Thanks

Comment: I needed to do this in Ubuntu 22.04 `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so`

Comment: Excellent. The only thing I would add is that as time goes by and versions changes, once you're in dist-packages doing a 'ls -l apt_pkg.cpython*' will allow you to see the current name of the file that's meant to be used in the 'sudo ln -s ...' command.

Answer (score 31):

This error will often occur when a newer version of python has been installed alongside an older version e.g;

- Ubuntu 18.04.1 ships with python version 3.6.6
- Installed ppa:deadsnakes/python3.7.1 or alternative
- Run a command that uses the apt_pkg module and get an error such as;

  ```
      from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
      import apt_pkg
  ```

When we install a non-distro python3 version with apt it will set a shared module directory to be that of python3 most usually it will be `/usr/lib/python3`.

Most of the time this will be ok, but under some circumstances the different versions of python rely on different libraries or shared objects/libraries than the other python version does, so as other answers have pointed out we need to link the .SO to the correct python version. So if we have python3.6 installed on a 64bit system then the apt_pkg .SO link would be

```
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

But the problem lies in the fact that when we install a newer python version the link will update to point to the newest python version, which leads to the error of apt_pkg module not being found.
By checking which version of python ships with your distro you can create the link as shown above.
Or we use a method to offer the command a choice of python versions to link the .SO such as;

```
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-{36m,35m,34m}-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Because python will create this link to the newest installed python version we give the command the option to choose from 3 python versions, of which it will choose the highest version given.

Comment: Running 18.04.2, your first recommendation worked for me and I could finally run the sudo apt-get update with no errors. Your second recommendation return an error saying apt-get.so was not a folder.

Answer (score 31):

I see everyone saying how to fix it with strange copying etc, but no one really said ***why*** the problem occurs.

So let me explain, for those of you who like me don't want to mess with system files only because someone on SO told them so.

---

The problem is that:

- many system scripts have python3 shebang hardcoded into them. You can check it yourself:

```sh
~$ grep -R "\#\!/usr/bin/python3" /usr/lib/*

/usr/lib/cnf-update-db:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/command-not-found:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstotiff:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertosag-gdi:#!/usr/bin/python3 -u
grep: /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-brf: Permission denied
/usr/lib/cups/backend/hpfax:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/language-selector/ls-dbus-backend:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/language_support_pkgs.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/MirrorTest.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/installdriver.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/openprinting.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/xmldriverprefs.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/smburi.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/ppds.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cupshelpers/debug.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/DistUpgrade/dist-upgrade.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Quirks/quirkreader.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
grep: /usr/lib/ssl/private: Permission denied
/usr/lib/system-service/system-service-d:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release-gtk:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/do-partial-upgrade:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/ubuntu-release-upgrader/check-new-release:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/update-notifier/backend_helper.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt_check.py:#!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check:#!/usr/bin/python3
```

- python apt package `python-apt`/`python3-apt` is a system package, so it's for default system python

**Thus, the scripts will always get the version currently linked to `python3`, but fail because the apt package is not present.**

---

**General solution: NEVER change default `python3` link. Ever.** This also applies to `python` link - if an app was written in Python2 with some old syntax elements that don't work in Python3, the app will not work.

[My terminal broke that way because I use Terminator, which is apparently written in Python2.7 not compatible with Python3.]

---

**Solutions presented here either suggest copying/linking the apt package files or changing `python3` link.**

Let's analyse both:

1. Copying/linking the apt package

This *shouldn't* be a problem because from around Python3.4 all python scripts work on newer versions as well.

So far. But it may break in the future - if you keep your system long enough.

2. Changing `python3` link back

This is a great solution because we can get back to "never ever changing the link"

---

*"But I like having to type just `python`!"* - I like it too! That's how I got to this problem in the first place!

1. **In general, you should avoid manually changing system links - use `update-alternatives` instead to link different versions**. This applies to any app with many versions. This will still break those system scripts (because it does change the link), but you can switch back and forth easily, without worrying whether you put link and dest in the right order or made a typo.
2. Consider using other name than `python`/`python3` for your link or alias.
3. Or add your own `python`/`python3` link to PATH (just like virtual environments do), without changing system links.

Comment: very helpful for new python users.

Comment: This should really be the top answer

Answer (score 25):

This worked for me on after updating python3.7 on ubuntu18.04

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Comment: This worked for me after upgrade **python 3.8** on ubuntu18.04.

Comment: This worked for me with **Python 3.8.5** with **Ubuntu 20.04**; the cause for trouble was having played around with the targets py2/py3 of the symbolic link /bin/usr/python. This confused some programs calling py3 which threw the OP's error. The other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64241654/5459638 contains useful information to understand what happened.

Answer (score 18):

The solution of [@user8178061](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612200/9885430) worked well but I did it with some modifications for my version wich is `python3.7` with Ubuntu

I replaced the `apt_pkg.cpython-3m-i386-linux-gnu.so` with `apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Here the two commands to execute:

`cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

`sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so`

Comment: This fixed my problem. This solves the problem if it was caused by switching the Python version from 3.6 to 3.7.

Comment: Thanks, had the same issue! Consider using `sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so` so it's clear what `apt_pkg.so` is.

Comment: Worked, but I had to change it to `sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so` for some reason

Answer (score 17):

1. Check your default Python 3 version:

   ```
   python3 --version
   Python 3.7.5
   ```
2. `cd` into `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` and check the `apt_pkg.*` files. You will find that there is none for your default Python version:

   ```
   ll apt_pkg.*
   apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
   ```
3. Create the symlink:

   ```
   sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
   ```

Comment: This one worked for me on Ubuntu 20.02 after upgrading the default Python to Python 3.9

Answer (score 11):

In my case I ran below command and it fixed the error:

`sudo apt install --reinstall python3 python python3-minimal --fix-broken`

Answer (score 9):

if you're using python 3.7 downgrade it to python 3.6 by updating Alternatives, This worked for me

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1

sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Comment: This worked for me with python3.6 but when I revert to python3.7, the error is still there

Answer (score 7):

For some reason my install was missing `apt_pkg.so` in the python3 dist-packages dir. (`apt_pkg.cpython-33m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` was there?!) but  and I had to make a symlink `apt_pkg.so -> apt_pkg.cpython-33m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

I'm not sure whether my upgrade was broken or why this was the case. It occured after trying to upgrade (precise->raring->quantal upgrade)

Comment: This was correct fix for me.  I caused this problem by using pip3 as root, even though I knew it was a bad idea.  I wanted to see how badly I'd get shocked if I put my finger in a light socket.  Answer is: pretty bad.  Also messing with the /etc/alternatives setup is not for the feint of heart.  Not for anybody who is a part time visitor.  I think crossing what python link pointed at which python was problem that started me down path to disaster.

Answer (score 5):

A last resort is `sudo cp /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
if the `ln` command is too much for you or somehow magically doesn't work.

`cp` above can also be `mv` if you are only dedicated to using one Python version.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to making a symbolic link for `apt_pkg.so`, you may want to make `apt_inst.so` in the same manner of `apt_pkg.so`.

```
ln -s apt_inst.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_inst.so
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, and upgraded to Python 3.7.  Here is the error that I had when trying to add a PPA

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I was able to fix this error by making symbolic link with my initial python 3.4 `apt_pkg.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`  by creating the following symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Comment: It looks like this solution was already proposed in at least 6 another answers to this question (and 3 more just suggested to copy the file instead of symlinking).

Comment: this simply works for me, thanks! One thing is before that we need to cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

Answer (score 3):

If you're using python 3.5, downgrade to 3.4. That's the safest move to do.

Under `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` you'll see `*34m*` which python 3.5 can't use. zhazha answer symlink to it.

Comment: how do you downgrade it?

Comment: why is the downgrade the safest actin?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to create the link but many other problems happened. So, you can select the old version of python to install things using:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

And return to the desirable version right after using the same command.
Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 WSL v1 (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS)

This [reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/dw02l8/no_module_named_apt_pkg/f917wm4?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) (slightly modified worked for me)

`sudo ln -sfn /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so`

Answer (score 1):

After spending 4 hours I have got this solution which finally worked for me I hope this will help...

It is important to understand that sometimes when you upgrade from an older python version some packages stay in the previous version path, so here is what I did:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Check the existence of a file named `apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` or 34m or 36m listing the files and when you find it, delete the current `apt_pkg.so` file in

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Finally create a link with the correct path using `apt_pkg.so` like this:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo ln -s apt_pkg.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Now you can try again and It should work.

Answer (score 1):

This variant work for me.

```
cd  /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
ls -la /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

If you get an error message saying too many levels of symbolic links as shown below:

```
cp: failed to access '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt_pkg.so': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

Then you need to simply unlink the apt_pkg.so file. Use the following command:

```
sudo unlink apt_pkg.so
```

And then use the command

```
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Good luck!

Original answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1227625

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers worked for me (I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3.6). So I finally solved the issue as following:

1- connect to the FTP of the server

2- go to the folder "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/"

3- duplicate the file "apt_pkg.cpython-3**5**m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"

4- rename this duplicated file to "apt_pkg.cpython-3**6**m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the cleanest solution for me is to rebuild the related library with your new Python version, in its specific space.

I'm doing this right now, switching from Python3.9 to Python3.10.1.

So:

> ```
> cd /tmp/
> apt source python3-apt
> cd python-apt-version-ecc
> python3-new-version setup.py build
> python3-new-version setup.py install
> ```

Done this also with dependencies packages (`software-properties`, `python-launchpadlib`, and so on), and now `add-apt-repository` works like a charm.

Which ones to recompile? Simply watch out the complains of running `add-apt-repository`.

By the way, I'm on `Ubuntu 21.04`, but the logic is the same on any Debian like system.

Answer (score -1):

Please review the following documentation.

It could help you to solve the problem.

[Solve the problem of replacing the python version with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'](http://www.programmersought.com/article/55001874709/)

Comment: please provide an answer here. You could copy and paste the commands and keep the link

Answer (score -4):

Please try to fix this by setting the locale variables:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"

export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: Try to be more specific and explain what these two commands are doing.

Comment: please add mode details to this answer. Did it work for you? what is this trying to achieve?

Answer (score -6):

Just in case it helps another, I finally solved this problem, that was apparently caused by python version conflicts, by redirecting the link python3, then redirecting it to the right python version:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python3
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4
```

You may need to enter the correct python version, found with:

```
python3 -V
```

Comment: remove python3 is bad idea :(
if you want link to python 3.4 use  :

ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3

Comment: It's never a good idea to tell people to remove things from there system unless it is really needed. Luckily /usr/bin/python3 is normally just a symbolic link anyway. I really think you should just delete this answer.

Comment: at least reinstall is safer... `sudo apt install --reinstall python3`