# python ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: ubuntu, python-3.x

when i try `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

ubuntu terminal show this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
```

though i tried `apt-get install python3-apt` but still not working(and i also tried to re-install again after removing) and i also tried `pip3 install apt-pkg` but it saying

```
Downloading/unpacking apt-pkg
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement apt-pkg
No distributions at all found for apt-pkg
Storing complete log in /home/kim/.pip/pip.log
```

and of course, import apt_pkg also not working in python3(but it is working in python2.7, i have two version of python one is 2.7 the other is 3.3)

how can i install this package on python3

Comment: answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg

Comment: `apt_pkg` is in the [python3-apt](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/python3-apt) package. Different releases and build architectures can be present in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, differentiated by filename tags such as `cpython-33m-x86_64-linux-gnu` vs `cpython-33m-i386-linux-gnu`. Check to make sure the right version is present.