# ModuleNotFoundError in tracebacks with Python3.6 on linux

Tags: python-3.x, exception, python-3.6

I [installed Python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get) by using [Jonathon Fernyhough's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

I made a string, using the new literal string interpolation, but I supplied an invalid format specifier. I not only got the expected `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`, but also the unexpected `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'`.

```
$ python3.6
Python 3.6.0 (default, Dec 29 2016, 21:40:36) 
[GCC 5.4.1 20161202] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> value = 4 * 20
>>> f'the value is {value:%A}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

I reported this to the [Python bug tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue29307). There it was noted that:

> It seems to be vendor's issue not CPython itself. This same issue also happens in Ubuntu 16.10's Python 3.6. Raise any exception can cause this:

```
Python 3.6.0b2 (default, Oct 11 2016, 05:27:10) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20161005] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> raise Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
>>>
```

> Also see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.6/+bug/1631367.

Finally, the issue was closed with the comment

> Yes, this appears to be the vendor's failure reporting infrastructure
>   that is failing.  Why they'd want a report for every traceback at the
>   interactive prompt is beyond me, but that appears to be what they are
>   trying to do.

My questions now are:

1. How do I interpret this comment? Is the vendor in this case Jonathon Fernyhough's PPA? And did he change something to to the Python code he distributes so that it tries to file a report for every Exception that produces a traceback?
2. Who do I need to notify or where do I need to file a bug to get this resolved?

Comment: I tend to recommend the [deadsnakes ppa](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes).

Comment: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes` is the way to go imho.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After I posted this question to Stackoverflow, Barry A. Warsaw made the following [comment](http://bugs.python.org/issue29307#msg285730) to the issue tracker

> Please understand that installing Python 3.6 from a random PPA does
>   *not* provide full support for this version of the interpreter.  Python 3.6 is not yet a supported version in any version of Ubuntu
>   (which I'm assuming your using), although we are working on it for
>   17.04.
>
> Very often, you can install a new Python 3 interpreter package and
>   many things will work because the Ubuntu infrastructure shares
>   pure-Python modules across all installed Python 3's.  Technically
>   speaking, they will all have /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages on their
>   sys.path so any third party pure-Python module built for a support
>   version of Python 3 will be importable by any (package-built)
>   installed version of Python 3.
>
> But that 1) is a long way from saying that those third-party modules
>   will work; 2) does *not* include any packages containing C extension
>   modules, which must be rebuilt for the specific interpreter version.
>
> Supporting a new version of Python is a long process, for which we are
>   just starting.  Please engage with ubuntu-devel@ubuntu.com for
>   details.
>
> Ubuntu does install a standard exception handler so that when Python
>   applications and such crash, we can gather crash statistics, so that
>   we can devote resources to fixing common problems and regressions. 
>   apport (which you see in the traceback) is that crash reporting
>   infrastructure.  apport calls apt_pkg, which is an (C++) extension
>   module and thus won't have been built for the version of Python 3.6
>   you installed from that PPA, unless of course the PPA owner (who I
>   don't know) has also done an archive-wide Python 3 rebuild. Since I'm
>   in the process of setting that up, and I know it's quite a bit of
>   work, I doubt that's been done for this rather random PPA.
>
> The ubuntu-devel mailing list is a better place to discuss the ongoing
>   work to bring Python 3.6 as a supported version on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 34):

I solved this issue for Python 3.6 by first installing the python-apt package for Python 3:

```
sudo apt install python3-apt
```

After that, I changed to the `dist-packages` directory and copied the `apt_pkg[...].so` file to the new default file name `apt_pkg.so`, to be also recognized by Python 3.6:

```
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-34m-i386-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Now all `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'` exceptions disappeared on expectedly thrown error messages.

Comment: `sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-34m-i386-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so` gives a:

`cp: cannot stat ‘apt_pkg.cpython-34m-i386-linux-gnu.so’: No such file or directory`

Instead I used:

    sudo cp apt_inst.cpython-34m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so

But now my error is:
```
    import apt_pkg
    ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_apt_pkg)
```

Comment: Worked for me too, Thanks

Comment: worked to symlink the `38` version file to `39` to remove the error message for me to get Python3.9 working on WSL with Ubuntu running

Answer (score 5):

If most voted answer does not work for you please try below steps (Keep in mind you must change **[version]**):

1. run this command `sudo apt install python3-apt`
2. go to directory `cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`
3. run `ls` to find correct version of `apt_pkg.cpython-[version]-i386-linux-gnu.so` in my case it was `35m`
4. create a symlink `sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-[version]-i386-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so` DON'T FORGET: type your [version]

**Troubleshouting**

If you get error `cp: cannot stat 'apt_pkg.cpython-[your-version]-i386-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory` try commands below:

1. `rm -rf apt_pkg.so`
2. create a symlink `sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-[version]-i386-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so` DON'T FORGET: type your [version]

Comment: unfortunately did not work. any other suggestion? I get the `cp: cannot stat...` but it the suggestion doesn't fix it as well

Comment: @lowercase00 did you check your `apt_pkg.cpython-` version?

Comment: This dirty workaround did the trick for me from *36m* to *37m*. Now it remains to be seen if that so references some symbol from the *Python* executable (or *.dll*) that was removed between the 2 versions :) . But @andreas's solution is a bit cleaner and will do the trick for multiple *Python* installations.

Answer (score 1):

I removed `python3-apt` and that seems to have solved it for Python 3.8

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3-apt
sudo apt-get install python3-apt
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg#comment18845703_13717755