# using pip3: module "importlib._bootstrap" has no attribute "SourceFileLoader"

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, pip

I have installed pip for python 3.6 on Ubuntu 14. After I run

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

to install pip3, it works very well. However, after installation, when I am trying to run

```
pip3 install packagename
```

to install a new package, something strange occurs:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
 register_loader-type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
AttributeError: module "importlib._bootstrap" has no attribute "SourceFileLoader"
```

It seems that I did nothing wrong, and I really cannot figure out the reason.

Comment: Does that happen for every package you try to install?

Comment: It looks like issue is with python version.

Comment: @SamChats yep… Actually every time I type "pip3" this problem occurs, such as "pip3 --version" etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354166/7976758

Comment: @phd Why did you post that. The reason people came here is because the first command of the top answer does not work.

Comment: Correct answer at this stage is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41720578/modulenotfounderror-in-tracebacks-with-python3-6-on-linux

Comment: > pip uninstall setuptools
> pip install setuptools
worked for me

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Faced the same problem. I think this is because `python3.6` and `pip3` were installed from different sources.
I suggest using python's inbuilt facility to install pip i.e

```
python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

This should install `pip3` and `pip3.x` where x in `python3.x`.
Same works for `python2` also.

Comment: '/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named ensurepip' Any ideas?

Comment: That's strange! According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html `ensurepip` is part of python standard library.
Are you sure you installed python correctly and is accessible as well?

Comment: Is `ensurepip` available on Ubuntu? On my Ubuntu environment, I can't import it. Maybe, on many other environments, `ensurepip` is not available.

Comment: @H.Jang
Yeah. Its a bug in Ubuntu.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.4/+bug/1290847

Comment: @azhar22k is `ensurepip` available for python3.7 installed from `deadsnakes/ppa`repository?

Comment: Hey @Ibrahim.H, haven't checked it myself so can't say

Comment: not working. I already reinstalled pip3 and pipenv

Answer (score 314):

If you're getting this error running `pip install dotenv`, this is because the package is called `python-dotenv` not `dotenv`.

This worked for me:

```
sudo pip install python-dotenv
```

Comment: I think this answer is specific to dotenv

Comment: `sudo pip3 install python-dotenv` if you have pip3 installed alongside pip for python2

Comment: Saved my life! `poetry add python-dotenv` :)

Comment: It is so bad that the package name used in import statement is different than the one used in installation

Comment: Agreed with @alramdein, especially because the dotenv package exists :) 
https://pypi.org/project/dotenv/

Answer (score 32):

Tried to install Tensorflow in venv on Windows 10 machine with python 3.8 and got the same issue.

What helped for me  was:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

Comment: Also helps for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I have `Pop!_OS 20.10` based on Ubuntu and this helped

Comment: helped also on Pop!_OS 21.10 as well

Comment: this helped me during the installation of Localstack via pip

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem on my ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.6. None of the above methods helped, but this one solved the problem:

```
pip3 uninstall setuptools
```

Comment: I had issues with fs-uae-launcher not starting on Debian Buster because:
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
Uninstalling setuptools fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, none of the above solution worked and this issue was annoying my day :)

Comment: `pip3 uninstall setuptools` make it worse
`pip3 install setuptools`same error as in topick

Answer (score 16):

I had the same error whatever I asked to pip. I gave a look to this page: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

That line is the one that solved my problem:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

Comment: After upgrading from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04 I had this problem with pip3. Nothing I'd found worked. This finally solved it.

Comment: On MacOS Monterey 12.6 and using python 3.9.9. This command fixed the issue while trying to install socketio 0.2.1

Answer (score 7):

When updating from python3.4 to python3.6 on ubuntu 14.04. The following solved me:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python3
```

Comment: This one worked for me, just added sudo to python3
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python3

Answer (score 7):

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

This command solved my issue. It fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are using an old version of `setuptools`, check up this [issue](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/378).

Answer (score 3):

If you face this issue in anaconda environment, simply upgrade `setuptools` using the following:

```
conda install -c conda-forge setuptools
```

Answer (score 3):

I had faced the same issue on Ubuntu 19.10 and now I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and faced the issue again. This issue is due to broken pip3. So whenever you enter pip3 and hit enter it will show the same error. So instead of using "pip3 uninstall setuptools" use the below code

```
python3 -m pip uninstall setuptools
```

It resolved my issue 3rd time

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem, this is the key:

```
curl -sS https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3
```

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same problem, which is solved by downloading the source files of the setuptools and installing the module manually.

The setuptools can be downloaded here:

```
https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/
```

After downloading, unzip the package first, then cd to the directory and run

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the error happened while trying to create a virtual env with python 3.8:

```
sudo virtualenv venv -ppython3.8
```

And after trying all the answers here, finally the problem solved by installing the new version of `virtualenv` *(20.0.7)*:

```
sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error message triggered by a slightly different situation which I'll mention here for anyone who finds this.

This same error also occurs when installing the [`distribute`](https://pypi.org/project/distribute/) Python package (which is currently just a compatibility layer in front of `setuptools`) in Python 3.6 or newer.

In my specific situation I discovered this as I was using [`pyzmail` which has been somewhat abandoned and depends on `distribute`](https://github.com/aspineux/pyzmail/issues/15#issuecomment-289242646).

```
Collecting distribute
  Downloading distribute-0.7.3.zip (145 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /var/lang/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ssqyqflj/distribute/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ssqyqflj/distribute/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-hgbjn0js
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ssqyqflj/distribute/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ssqyqflj/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ssqyqflj/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ssqyqflj/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.install import install
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ssqyqflj/distribute/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ssqyqflj/distribute/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ssqyqflj/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to install the Slate package in Windows 10, Python 3.7.4 version:

> AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

The instruction that generated the error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install slate
```

The instruction that worked:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install https://github.com/timClicks/slate/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 6, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 
1479, in <module>
```

Mine looked pretty similar, but for some reason I had a python installation in my home directory `.local` folder.

I did some of the other answers in this thread to ensure I had good local copy of python, then did:

```
rm -rf ~/.local
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my cloud computer. If all above didn't work for you don't worry. Here's how I resolved it:

1. Download the `pip` file (`pip-version.tar.gz`) from:

```
https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files
```

For cloud, use this

```
curl https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/76/66066b7bc71817238924c7e4b448abdb17eb0c92d645769c223f9ace478f/pip-20.0.2.tar.gz --output pip.tar.gz
```

2. Extract the content of the file and cd into the directory.
3. Run the following in the directory

```
python3 setup.py install --user
```

You should have pip3 working without errors.

Comment: Still get same error - Ubuntu 14: AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

Answer (score 0):

Just go inside the `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`, first copy  `setuptools` file somewhere and then delete the `setuptools`. Everything will be okay for deleting you can use:

```
sudo rm -r setuptools
```

for copying

```
sudo cp -r setuptools /...Desktop/
```

After that if it gives errors just:

```
sudo pip3 install setuptools==3.8.1
```

to download again.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install setuptools --upgrade
```

This also cured the issue on Python 3.9 running on Windows 10 and even on a custom Docker image.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue while using `docker-compose`. This exact error can be caused by not being the root user. Running the same commands with `sudo` fixed it for me. I don't not have `setup-tools` installed, and I'm running `pip3`. My issue was that IntelliJ didn't have sudo rights, so i had to do it from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Above solutions were not working in my case for Ubuntu 20

If you run the following command:

```sh
sudo apt install python3-setuptools
```

Then you might get the result:

```sh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-setuptools is already the newest version (45.2.0-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But to actually solve it and re-install setuptools try following commands:

```sh
sudo apt download python3-setuptools
sudo dpkg -i python3-setuptools_45.2.0-1_all.deb
```

Note: Change the version of the python package that is downloaded