# How do I solve error "dotenv installation error" on pycharm

Tags: python, pip, dotenv

I am trying to install dotenv package on pycharm edu,but keep getting error that reads "AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader' "

I tried to solve this using the python terminal by running command "pip install --user dotenv" as root user but still got the same error

command output reads as follows

```
Collecting dotenv
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e2/46/3754073706e31670eed18bfa8a879305b56a471db15f20523c2427b10078/dotenv-0.0.5.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 194, in setup_context
    __import__('setuptools')
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging11/dotenv/setup.py", line 23, in <module>
    scripts=['scripts/dotenv']
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 269, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 826, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1092, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1104, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 663, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 693, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 873, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1101, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1087, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 233, in run_setup
    with setup_context(setup_dir):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 99, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
    saved_exc.resume()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
    six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 194, in setup_context
    __import__('setuptools')
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/tmp/easy_install-vzgpp8in/distribute-0.7.3/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pycharm-packaging11/dotenv/"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using pip3: module "importlib.\_bootstrap" has no attribute "SourceFileLoader"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761958/using-pip3-module-importlib-bootstrap-has-no-attribute-sourcefileloader)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+%27importlib._bootstrap%27+has+no+attribute+%27SourceFileLoader%27

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install `python-dotenv` and then import `dotenv` package instead of `python-dotenv`, because the latter doesn`t work

Answer (score 53):

Try installing "python-dotenv" package instead of "dotenv". This should solve the problem.

`sudo pip install python-dotenv`

[image]