# trying to install docplex on python Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, docplex

Collecting docplex

```
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/06/de7833f2e70d51286611a2676f130f0978d2c16f65047cb965d0af579d08/docplex-2.12.182.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\radoslaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Radoslaw\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b1xxmtgb\\docplex\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Radoslaw\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-b1xxmtgb\\docplex\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Radoslaw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b1xxmtgb\docplex\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Radoslaw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b1xxmtgb\docplex\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\radoslaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension
      File "c:\users\radoslaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "c:\users\radoslaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 17, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "c:\users\radoslaw\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1519, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Please help me, it's so important for me

Comment: Can you check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761958/using-pip3-module-importlib-bootstrap-has-no-attribute-sourcefileloader It reports the same error and has some solutions.

Comment: I have seen that but it doesnt work