# using pip3: module “importlib._bootstrap” has no attribute “SourceFileLoader”

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, bulbs

I want to install the graph based database library `bulb`. However when I try to do so I get:

```
(plA_env) (base) antoi@LAPTOP-UTL8OHHO:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/plAtform/plAtform$ python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
Looking in links: /tmp/tmpz62_ljle
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/plAtform/plA_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (41.2.0)
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/plAtform/plA_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages (19.2.3)
(plA_env) (base) antoi@LAPTOP-UTL8OHHO:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/plAtform/plAtform$ pip install bulbs
Collecting bulbs
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7e/9c/fc1eb0de57ab9390e1edce7c61184d160e421fdb9643fde59a0334c85d34/bulbs-0.3.29-20140417.tar.gz
Collecting distribute (from bulbs)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/ad/1fde06877a8d7d5c9b60eff7de2d452f639916ae1d48f0b8f97bf97e570a/distribute-0.7.3.zip
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/plAtform/plA_env/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-x73ckeds/distribute/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-x73ckeds/distribute/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-x73ckeds/distribute/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x73ckeds/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x73ckeds/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x73ckeds/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.install import install
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x73ckeds/distribute/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x73ckeds/distribute/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
      File "/tmp/pip-install-x73ckeds/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I already checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761958/using-pip3-module-importlib-bootstrap-has-no-attribute-sourcefileloader?answertab=active#tab-top) but it all gives the error.

I am using Windows 10 and python 3.8.