# PyQt ERROR: Command errored out with exit status Python

Tags: python

Question: I would like to install PyQt-fit.

I upgrade the pip and the supertools wheel

version pip: 20.0.2 and 1.0.1 for supertools.

I don't know what is going on.

```
C:\Users\Flor>pip install supertools
Requirement already satisfied: supertools in c:\users\flor\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (1.0.1)
```

ERROR:

```
C:\Users\Flor>python373 -m pip install --user PyQt-Fit
Collecting PyQt-Fit
  Using cached PyQt-Fit-1.4.0.tar.gz (104 kB)
Collecting distribute>=0.6
  Using cached distribute-0.7.3.zip (145 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Flor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python373.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Flor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3jhprspf\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Flor\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3jhprspf\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Flor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jhprspf\distribute\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Flor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jhprspf\distribute\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Flor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jhprspf\distribute\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "C:\Users\Flor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jhprspf\distribute\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "C:\Users\Flor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jhprspf\distribute\setuptools\dist.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.install import install
      File "C:\Users\Flor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jhprspf\distribute\setuptools\command\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "C:\Users\Flor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jhprspf\distribute\setuptools\command\install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
      File "C:\Users\Flor\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jhprspf\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Are you trying to install them in different versions of python? Does `pip` correspond to `python373` ?

Comment: Yes it's the same :/

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing and also try `python373 -m pip install --user supertools`

Comment: I did it and nothing. I tried too install python 3.8.2 and then install supertools and then PyQt-Fit and nothing...

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761958/using-pip3-module-importlib-bootstrap-has-no-attribute-sourcefileloader) ?