# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info

Tags: python, google-api, pip, installation, gmail-api

I am trying to install the google-api-python-client and I keep getting this error:
`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info`

More specifically it happens when it is collecting 'googleapis-common-protos<2.0dev,>=1.6.0'. Any tips on how to solve this and has this happened to someone else? I have the latest version of python and pip

Here is the full command output:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\astho_wgi3ujz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ASTHO_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x0cydaaa\\googleapis-common-protos\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ASTHO_~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-x0cydaaa\\googleapis-common-protos\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\ASTHO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-c2ymsdk9'
         cwd: C:\Users\ASTHO_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-x0cydaaa\googleapis-common-protos\
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\astho_wgi3ujz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension
      File "c:\users\astho_wgi3ujz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "c:\users\astho_wgi3ujz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module>
        import pkg_resources
      File "c:\users\astho_wgi3ujz\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 1479, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761958/using-pip3-module-importlib-bootstrap-has-no-attribute-sourcefileloader
`python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError%3A+module+importlib._bootstrap+has+no+attribute+SourceFileLoader

Comment: Can you provide your python version? Also, are you using a virtual environment? try `pip install python-dotenv` then `pip install google-api-python=client`