# Unable to install dotenv on Windows

Tags: python, pip, dotenv

I never thought I'd be using Stack Overflow, but here I am!

I am unable to install DotEnv on Windows, when I execute `pip install dotenv` with its optional flags, this error is thrown:

```
Collecting dotenv
  Using cached dotenv-0.0.5.tar.gz (2.4 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Damian Freeman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bdy5mww4\\dotenv\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Damian Freeman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-bdy5mww4\\dotenv\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-k9desg5s'
         cwd: C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bdy5mww4\dotenv\
    Complete output (52 lines):
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Damian Freeman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-djm3svo6\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Damian Freeman\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-djm3svo6\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-s15217m9'
             cwd: C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-djm3svo6\distribute\
        Complete output (15 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-djm3svo6\distribute\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
            from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
          File "C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-djm3svo6\distribute\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
            from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
          File "C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-djm3svo6\distribute\setuptools\dist.py", line 7, in <module>
            from setuptools.command.install import install
          File "C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-djm3svo6\distribute\setuptools\command\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
            from setuptools.command import install_scripts
          File "C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-djm3svo6\distribute\setuptools\command\install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
            from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
          File "C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-djm3svo6\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
            register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
        AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "c:\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\python38\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\DAMIAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpfnchk15m', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Damian Freeman\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bdy5mww4\dotenv\setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        setup(name='dotenv',
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 143, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 138, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 695, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 754, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['c:\\python38\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\DAMIAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpfnchk15m', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

However, I read on an older thread to install DotEnv with `pip install python-dotenv` but said "solution" was not a fix to my problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using pip3: module "importlib.\_bootstrap" has no attribute "SourceFileLoader"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44761958/using-pip3-module-importlib-bootstrap-has-no-attribute-sourcefileloader)

Comment: I *don't* think so... I am able to install discord.py with the same command, and other modules.

Comment: Error is identical, though

Comment: Yeah... I see that...

Comment: Could you try `python -m pip install dotenv` instead? Do you have multiple installs of Python? Where did you obtain your Python install from (website, Windows Store, ...)?

Answer (score 33):

You are installing dotenv instead of python-dotenv.Use this command:

```
pip install -U python-dotenv
```

Refer this [issue](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/issues/53)

Comment: If you are using python notebooks, then you can install it directly and just run the notebook cell.

Comment: If you are not , then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code).If this doesn't solve the issue then open a new question with detailed problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Mac and this answer helped end 25 minutes of `pipenv lock --clear && pipenv lock --pre --clear`, `rm -f`'ing the `Pipfile.lock` file, replacing it with `pipenv update`, `pipenv install && pipenv shell`, and trying `pipenv install dotenv` one more time.  Thanks!