# every action shows: AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'

Tags: python, python-3.7, attributeerror

I have been trying to fix this error for days and I am running out of ideas.

I am working on a webapp and I tried to install socketIO to try it out. Every since I attempted to install that package, I keep getting the "AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'" message for almost anything I do.
I get the error when I try to install a package.
I get the error when I try to start the app by running "flask run"

I've tried to start other projects with a different venv but I still get the same error for every single one of those.

"python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade" returns "Requirement already up-to-date"
I tried to uninstall setuptools but when I try to reinstall it gives me the same attributeerror aswell.
I manually downloaded pip3 and installed it as discribed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60778810/17014170
I even tried to reinstall my coding program because I thought there might be an error with it. But nothing worked.
I can't run any of my programs and I'm starting to get desperate.
Does anybody know how to get rid of this error?
I don't need to install socketIO or any other package anymore, I just need to be able to use "flask run" again to run my apps.

I am working on Windows 10 with Python 3.7

Edit:
I've installed Python 3.9 and created a new venv. My programs work with that.
I'd still like to know if there is any way to fix my 3.7 python installation, if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: For a start, search for the error message online (just so you know what it means) and extract a [mcve] from your code. Include the latter and the full error output in your question. As a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask] as well.

Comment: Same for me -- python broke after installing socketio

Answer (score 3):

I did a bit of research and found `socketio` is an unmaintained package. Unfortunately, it would attempt to install `setuptools==3.3` (while the current version is 62.1.0) [^1](https://github.com/thonny/thonny/issues/1241). Ever since I installed `socketio` with `pip install socketio`, it result in the below error whenever I try to run `pip`:

```
AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
```

To solve this, I upgraded `setuptools` with the below command:

```sh
python3 -m pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly my python 3.9.6 broke after pip installing socketio -- or at least it is an odd coincidence!

Anyhow, I "fixed" my python by installing 3.9.7 (I downloaded the Mac OS package and installed it that way, not with an env tool).

Also as well, socketio started to work after doing that.