# Pip doesn't let me install pyzmail, I always get the same error no matter what I try

Tags: python, pip, pyzmail

So I'm following along "Automate the boring stuff" by Al Sweigart. And he uses pyzmail in the book. Naturally I'm going to want to use it too in order to follow along with the book. I've tried every single thing on the internet - and it's just frustrating. Can somebody tell me how to fix this please? I just can't get this damn pyzmail module installed. I've even tried virtual environments. I get this error no matter what, it's like it's destined to be and god wants me to suffer in the cmd prompt and google for 3 hours .

```
.\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0>pip install pyzmail
Collecting pyzmail
  Using cached pyzmail-1.0.3.tar.gz (57 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [2 lines of output]
      error in pyzmail setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
      VERSION 1.0.3
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

This is the error. I find it really confusing.

```
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that it will work but that's what I found.

**setuptools>=58** breaks support for **use_2to3** that is why you are facing this error

Consider downgrading the setuptools to version 57.

```
pip install -I setuptools==57.5.0
```

That is the latest 57 version.

Also, you may consider not using this library.

**UPDATE**

As I understood, this package is abandoned and the last release was in May 2014. **Downgrading the setuptools will not work**. This package fails in setting up **an abandoned distribute library**.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64868635/10906390) to the same problem and answer.

Comment: It's still giving me metadata-generation-failed. Thanks for the answer tho, appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda researched this topic, tried it by myself and found another unresolvable error.

Answer (score 0):

I found this little tidbit in the Q&A section of the Udemy course.

"Make sure if you are on python 3.6 and up to use  pip install pyzmail36"

I used pymail36 instead of just pyzmail and the package install worked with no errors. Hope this helps.

Comment: pyzmail36 worked for me thanks