# python add-apt-repository: ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: python, importerror, apt

When I try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kirillshkrogalev/ffmpeg-next
```

in Ubuntu, the terminal show this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

I have two version of python, one is 2.7 the other is 3.5 .

How can I install this package on python3.5?

Comment: Why would you want to install the package for Python 3.5? Most likely it's an Ubuntu specific system package, which comes bundled with the default system Python (which is 2.7.x)

Comment: Actually you are not installing anything, you only add a ppa to the system. To me this looks like a bug in `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` (which is a Python3 script).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python-dev installation error: ImportError: No module named apt\_pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg)

Answer (score 47):

I had something quite different than this. Mine failed with

> `No module named 'softwareproperties'`

My solution is:

```
sudo vim /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
Change package header from `python3` to `python3.4` (or lower)
```

This may happen when you recently *upgraded* or *added* another `python3` package.

Comment: I had to edit it to `python3.5` on Ubuntu 16.04 and it worked. Thanks .

Comment: Manually editing package headers of system scripts didn't work for me on 16.04 and seems error-prone in the first place. To me this looks like a bug in `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository`. I ended up manually adding the ppa (and importing the key).

Comment: @jangroth I totally agree, add your solution as an answer :)

Comment: It's just point to the correct version of python. Hard is to find if you have many installed

Comment: tks, changing hashbang to python3.5, but changing to python3.4 works!

Comment: if you are brave enough, you can run 
`sudo rpl -w "python3" "python$(python3 --version | awk '{print $2}')"  /usr/bin/add-apt-repository` to replace package header with current python version.

Comment: I decided to isolate the issue and try with different python versions `3.9` `3.8` `3.7` `3.6`
The one that worked for me `#!/usr/bin/python3.6`

Answer (score 17):

ubuntu 18.04:

```
sudo vim /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
```

Change package header from `python3` to `python3.6`

it's work for me

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works currently . But still All of these seems to be hacky ! , is there an official fix to this problem ?

Comment: Worked for me also - Ubuntu 18.04 Jetson Nano.

Answer (score 9):

Just chiming in since the version numbers may have changed.

**Summary of fix: pointing my `python3` to python 3.5 instead of 3.6**

```
cd /usr/bin
rm python3
ln -s python3.5 python3
```

**Detail**: I had this same problem and found that `/usr/bin/add-apt-repository` had a shebang hint to use `/usr/bin/python3` which is pointing to 3.6. However I also have 3.5 on my system and have to toggle them often, so I toggled it back and `add-apt-repository` now works.

Comment: Worked for me on WSL Ubunutu 16.04.4. I was having the same error as the OP.

Comment: Glad this helped. Given the supposed backwards compatibility of 3.6/3.5, it's weird to me that I used to have issues where Ubuntu wouldn't work properly with 3.6. Notably, my Terminal windows wouldn't start up until I toggled back to 3.5. In current Ubuntu I think 3.6 is now standard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Ubuntu 20.04 and python3 pointing to python3.6.

I don't like to edit system file or similar (eg. /usr/bin/add-apt-repository) and change symlinks of certain commands (python is quite "special"). I suggest to follow the Ubuntu way to manage alternative versions of same command.

**I had python3 pointing to python3.6 but python3.8 installed too so I updated alternatives to make coexist 3.6 and 3.8.**

My proposed solution is to make python3 pointing to last installed version you have using thee "Ubuntu way" managing alternative.

1. Install last python3 version available. Mabe you have it or maybe you don't.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install python3
```

2. Check now which is your version of python3

```
python3 --version
```

3. If it pointing to last (eg. 3.8), you should solved your problem. If python3 is still pointing to a lower version (eg. 3.6), check where last is...

```
which python3.8
```

4. Now managing python 3 alternatives. Check if alternatives about python3 exists.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

5. If some are listed, check if last version installed is in and if it is choose it and you should solve your problem. Otherwise remember the highest value of Priority. Ubuntu will use the alternative with highest value. Exit typing Enter button.
6. Add last version installed as alternative. Here I use the dicimal part of version as priority. The command need  python3

```
sudo update-alternatives /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 8
```

7. If you need, add the others version of python3... (lower priority!!!)
   Now your python3 is pointing to last version available in "Ubuntu style". (and the problem should be solved).

Answer (score 0):

IMO, there is a neater solution to bypass the modification of a system file: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `UBUNTU`, change to `python3.8` version or install it

```
sudo apt install python3.8-dev
```

and after run

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that everything that contains

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
```

Is a Python issue. To resolve it, one must set the correct python version. It depends on many factors what "correct version" means

##### Check python versions in the system

```sh
sudo apt list --installed | grep python*
```

##### Find what is at `/usr/bin`

```sh
ls -lha /usr/bin/python*
```

- Locate the Python file that is generating the error

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/BAR/FOO # Is a python file and it varies
  # For the case in this question the file is at
  # /usr/bin/add-apt-repository
```

- Open the file with `sudo` and add the "correct python version"

```sh
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

# Above should be the first line of the file
```

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me** :

```
sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall
cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).