# while adding this repo in ubuntu sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng error

Tags: python, ruby, docker, ubuntu

i have tired adding this ruby repo for installing 2.4 version of ruby, the error message is shown bellow

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
```

but i got this error i have tried all this links

[python add-apt-repository: ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386097/python-add-apt-repository-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg)

[How to fix 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56218562/how-to-fix-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-apt-pkg)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods and find if it works

```
apt-get remove --purge python-apt
```

and then

```
apt-get install python-apt
```

Comment: Are you executing this command in the `Dockerfile` ?