# How to import python3 lib in python3.6

Tags: python, linux

I have virtual environment created for python 3.6. And I have install `python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit` package with `apt-get`. The package have installed in global python3.5 and its working, but if I try to import it from venv python3.6 there is import error... How can I install this package in my virtual environment? Or if this is not possible how can I use global package installed in 3.5 in my virtualenv 3.6 python.

## Running with global python3.5

```
(virtualenv) 
~/vcs-ss/sst  master ✗                                                                                                                         5d ▴ ⚑ ✚ ◒  
▶ python3.5 -c 'import PyQt5.QtWebKit; print(PyQt5.QtWebKit.__file__)'
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtWebKit.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

## Running with python3.6 from venv

```
(virtualenv) 
~/vcs-ss/sst  master ✗                                                                                                                         5d ▴ ⚑ ✚ ◒  
▶ python3.6 test/e2e/browser.py     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/e2e/browser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/e2e/browser.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebKit'
```

Comment: Have you tried using pip to install it?

Comment: Try `sudo pip3 install pyqt5` in your venv.

Comment: @BrightOne I have already done this QtWebKit is not in standard qyqt5 library (its not included).

Comment: @Professor_Joykill Lol Yes.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use system packages inside a virtual environment, you have to use [`--system-site-packages`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/#cmdoption-system-site-packages) option when creating virtual env:

```
virtualenv --python=python3.6 --system-site-packages env
```

The same switch is available in Python3's [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Much better option is (if applicable in your case) to install all packages inside your virtual env, using `pip`.

Comment: I have `virtualenv -p python3.6 --distribute --system-site-packages venv` but still it seems that it recognize system site packages from global 3.6 python.

Comment: From your updated question, looks like `python-apt` package is missing. Try: `apt-get install python-apt`.

Comment: Have you tried `apt-get remove --purge python-apt` and then reinstall? Like this [answer (and comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13717755/404556) suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the contents of the package (using `dpkg --listfiles python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit`) you'll probably see something like this:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtWebKit.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtWebKit.pyi
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtWebKitWidgets.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtWebKitWidgets.pyi
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit
/usr/share/doc/python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit/copyright
/usr/share/doc/python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit/changelog.Debian.gz
```

The package installs binary modules compiled for a specific python version (in this case: cpython-35m), you won't be able to use those from a python3.6 installation/venv directly because of the incompatible binary names.

For that to work you'd need to symlink all the `.so` files in the `PyQt5` directory to your venv and there change `cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu` to `cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu`. Same for the `sip` libraries, as those are requiered by PyQt5. And that will only work if the ABI is compatible between the two versions.

A quick test with the versions mentioned above shows it works at least for simple scripts, but I can't give any guarantee.

Comment: `from PyQt5.QtWebKit import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Network.so.5: symbol _Z15qIsEffectiveTLDRK7QString, version Qt_5 not defined in file libQt5Core.so.5 with link time reference`