# Can't install Telegram on Debian : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: linux, telegram, apt

I am Debian user.

I run the code in the shell as a root:

I want to install telegram with below command :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/telegram

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install telegram
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 11, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, shortcut_handler
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 27, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

how can I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg

Comment: are you sure this link is my answer ??

Comment: Fix this error message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg', and you will probably fix your issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww But why you vote down my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tow way to install `telegram` on debian:

1) The `telegram` package can be installed through `snap`.

```
# apt install snapd
```

To find a package:

```
snap find telegram
```

Sample output:

```
Name                 Version     Developer       Notes  Summary
telegram-sergiusens  1.2.6       sergiusens      -      Telegram desktop client
telegram-cli         1.4.5       marius-quabeck  -      Command-line interface for Telegram. Uses the readline interface.
telegram-desktop     1.2.17      3v1n0           -      Official desktop client for the Telegram messenger
ubuntu-social-kit    3           keshavnrj       -      Bring social media apps to Ubuntu Desktop
squirrelbot          1.1.2       xordspar0       -      A Telegram bot that stashes away links that you send it
mup-plugins          2017.04.19  niemeyer        -      mup IRC and Telegram bot - plugins side
mup-accounts         2016.09.24  niemeyer        -      mup IRC and Telegram bot - account connection side
shell2telegram       1.7         msoap           -      Telegram bot constructor from command-line
```

To install `telegram`:

```
# snap install telegram-desktop
```

2) The package `telegram-desktop` is available on [`stretch-backports`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch-backports/telegram-desktop). Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` by adding the following line:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main
```

Save then run:

```
# apt update
# apt install telegram-desktop
```

The package is available also for debian Buster and Sid.

Remove the `ppa:atareao/telegram` (Under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) and see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg) linked by @aicastell to fix the error.

Answer (score 1):

why you want to download and install telegram from PPA ?!
follow me :
**1)** Download Telegram Desktop from [Telegram.Org](https://desktop.telegram.org/)
**2)** Extract archive to /opt
**3)** execute /opt/Telegram/Telegram

Note : Telegram app automatically install telegramdesktop.desktop file on your application menu (~/.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop) . next time only click on icon .

FINE .