# Eror while updating packages from terminal in linux mint

Tags: terminal, linux-mint

i need help. since 5 days before, i tried to update packages in Mint using this command

> sudo apt update

but, at the end of the process, the terminal gives me traceback

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in 
>       from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
>     File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in 
>       import apt_pkg
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
>   E: Sub-process returned an error code

i tried to find the solution to fix this, but i can't. does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python-dev installation error: ImportError: No module named apt\_pkg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13708180/python-dev-installation-error-importerror-no-module-named-apt-pkg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the apt-get also doesn't work, can you try this? Most probably, apt_pkg is not in the correct path.

`cd /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

`ls -la /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`

Look for any file of the format `apt_pkg.cpython-` and so on. Copy that file's name. And replace `apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` with the copied file's name in the command below, and hit enter.

`sudo cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so apt_pkg.so`

Comment: i tried this, and the result still error

cp: cannot stat 'apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or director

Comment: Try this : `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt`. Was the apt_pkg file not visible after listing files, i.e. above second step?

Comment: this is apt_pkg, isn't it?

-rw-r--r--  1 root root 322972 Jan 25 05:06 apt_pkg.cpython-36m-i386-linux-gnu.so
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   8900 Jan 25 05:06 apt_pkg.pyi

Comment: Okay, I'll modify my answer based on your needs. Try that.

Comment: i tried it, and it works! i can update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, and autoremove with no error. thanks for your help brother

Answer (score 0):

I also had the issue with "cp: cannot stat 'apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': No such file or directory while I was as super user. I did the same command withouth the sudo command and it worked fine. I have in my system python 3.5, 3.6 and 3.7, so I do not think the version of python is a problem.

```
cp apt_pkg.cpython-36m-x86-64-linux-gnu.so.so apt_pkg.so
```

I hope this help someone now at 2022 :D

Regards.