# Ubuntu 22.04 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Tags: python, ubuntu

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 29, in

```
import apt_pkg
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier-common (--configure):
installed update-notifier-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of update-notifier:
update-notifier depends on update-notifier-common (= 3.192.54); however:
Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package update-notifier (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop:
ubuntu-desktop depends on update-notifier; however:
Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-desktop-minimal:
ubuntu-desktop-minimal depends on update-notifier; however:
Package update-notifier is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-desktop-minimal (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:

update-notifier-common

update-notifier

ubuntu-desktop

ubuntu-desktop-minimal

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

**I am facing the above error, While running : $ sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall**

**Some one please Help**

Comment: I found this [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13708180/17597213) and thought it might help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.